# evitar que se corte un texto en la celda de una tabla html

Tags: html, css

¿Como puedo hacer para que la celda de una tabla html ocupe el largo de un texto y no se corte en pedazos ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Puedes usar en los estilos de la tabla `white-space: pre-wrap` o `white-space:nowrap`

Comment: ¿Que esperas que suceda si la celada no puede expandirse mas y el texto no cabe? La pregunta viene pues la tabla se expandira hasta que otra regla la detenga. Si en ese caso aun no entra el texto, ... ¿que quieres que pase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar `white-space: pre-line o white-space:pre-wrap` así:

```
<table class="espacios">
   <tr>
      <td>FOLIO METPAB-19215</td>
      <td>FOLIO METPAB-19215</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

y en el css:

```
.espacios{
  white-space: pre-wrap;
}
```

o

```
.espacios{
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Usa una combinación de `overflow: hidden`, `white-space:nowrap;` y por último `text-overflow: ellipsis` para indicar continuación de texto.

Debes especificar un ancho de columna con `max-width` para que la tabla no se estire a todo lo largo.

```css
td {
  max-width: 250px;
  font-size: 40px;
  border: solid 2px gray;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum dolor amet. Lorem ipsum dolor amet. Lorem ipsum dolor amet.
    </td>
    <td>
      Lorem ipsum dolor amet. Lorem ipsum dolor amet. Lorem ipsum dolor amet.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```